# Split text and select random from text file

Tags: java

I have a text file where each passage of text is separated by `###`

Text File:

```
Text 1

###

Text 2

###

Text 3

###
Text 4
```

Currently the code below reads the whole text file but I want to select a random piece of text which as mentioned is separated from other text due to the `###`. How can this be implemented?

```
private void setContent(){
        String text = "";

        try {
            // file to inputstream
            InputStream input = getAssets().open("files/jokes.txt");
            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
            // byte buffer into a string
            text = new String(buffer);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        contentText.setText(text);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by splitting the text with the `###` string as delimeter:

```
String [] textParts = text.split("###");
```

and then you can choose a random part like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int  randomIndex = rand.nextInt(textParts.length());
String randomTextPart = textParts[randomIndex];
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for this

```
//separate whole text into pieces using separator 
String[] allPieces = text.split("###");
//select random text piece from all text pieces
String randomPiece = allPieces[new Random().nextInt(allPieces.length)];
```

Comment: An explanation for this code would be nice.

Comment: If you consider `###` to be a "separator line" you could also include the line break into the pattern, i.e. write `... text.split("###\n")`. Alternatively remove leading and trailing spaces in the passage text using trim: `... = allPieces[new Random().nextInt(allPieces.length)].trim();`

Answer (score 0):

Change your String to an array of String and read each line as a new element to the array.

Then you can use Random to generate a random number between 0 and your array length.

Use that number to get a random text from your array of read lines!

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend the `#`-based format as it will break when there is a `#` in the actual text. Also, there are plenty of file formats already that can do this for you (e.g. XML, JSON, etc.).

However, to solve your problem you could use the `String.split()` method. It takes in a separator and splits the text at all occurences of the separator. Then you select a random item from the returned Array using `Math.random()` or a new instance of the `Random` class.

*Edit: Seeing that the OP has changed the question, you will now need to use `###` as a separator instead of `#` as before.*

Example:

```
private void setContent(){
    String text = "";

    try {
        // file to inputstream
        InputStream input = getAssets().open("files/jokes.txt");
        int size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();
        // byte buffer into a string
        text = new String(buffer);

        String[] jokes = text.split("###");
        String yourJoke = jokes[(int)(Math.random() * jokes.length)];
        // Do something with your joke

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    contentText.setText(text);

}
```

Comment: Given the example text file and the filename used in the code ("files/jokes.txt") one can assume the OP is trying to read a "foreign" file in a given file format, i.e. a format the OP cannot control. So changing to a different file format does not seem to be an option.

Comment: @UdoBorkowski That he uses a text file does not mean anything. It could just be that everyone starts out like this. My first save files were like this too, so I told the OP that *I don't recommend it*. But then I proceeded to give a working answer. I don't know if you're the downvoter but if so, I don't see that as a reason to downvote.

Comment: @UdoBorkowski Before the edit he made, there was only one `#` in between the entries. You can easily see that here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50844966/revisions. My answer was before that edit.

Comment: @UdoBorkowski Not to mention the fact that it's against the rules to edit questions in a way that renders any given answers wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I wasn't aware of the OP's edits ('#' --> '###'). With the original post in mind my comment does not make sense. I removed my comment and the downvote.